# Webmapping with pgRouting and Mapserver for Beginners

Tags: web-mapping, mapserver, pgrouting

I want to use pgRouting for showing shortest path on hiking trails. I created web map so I need to enable users when they click on start and end point somewhere on hiking trails, that it shows shortest path between those two points. I am beginner with it, so I just need to tell me where to start. I have those lines in postgis database and I am working with phpPgAdmin and Mapserver.

Comment: This question is much too broad. You should try some books on web mapping, first.

Comment: I developed web map which need to have this shortest path function. I don't think it is too broad. I just want you to tell me how to start. I am beginner with pgRouting, not with web mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll need to get pgRouting running. For a tutorial check: [A Beginner’s Guide to pgRouting](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/).

The simplest approach is to do node-to-node routing using shortest_path().

You'll need to enable the user to pick start and end node for their routings. For example code check: [Picking a Feature’s Attribute Value From a WMS Layer With OpenLayers](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/picking-a-features-attribute-value-from-a-wms-layer-with-openlayers/)

In Mapscript, you can then tie a "Get Routing" button to a function that loads a new layer based on the shortest_path() query.

---

Update:

This is a great tutorial for creating a webmap with routing functionality: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoext_client.html
It is based on OpenLayers with GeoExt and pgRouting, but it's easy to adjust it to any other routing webservice.

Comment: UGh, our IT just blocked wordpress.com, can you provide a direct link so I can wget it perhaps?

Comment: @dassouki use Google Translate then hit the Orginal option (top right corner) http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Funderdark.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F03%2F17%2Fpicking-a-features-attribute-value-from-a-wms-layer-with-openlayers%2F&anno=2 too work around your IT url blocker...

Comment: @Mapperz - Still Blocked